# trouble installing pear on Mac 10.9 with MAMP installed

Tags: php, macos, pear

Ok, I'm using a MacBook and have MAMP PRO installed for PHP environment.

I'm trying to use Pear to install PHPUnit, but can't get it working. PHPUnit tells me `pear: command not found`

I came across a tutorial that suggests using `sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar` to install pear, but when I run it, I get the following:

```
[PEAR] Archive_Tar    - already installed: 1.3.7
[PEAR] Console_Getopt - already installed: 1.3.0
[PEAR] Structures_Graph- already installed: 1.0.4
[PEAR] XML_Util       - already installed: 1.2.1
[PEAR] PEAR           - already installed: 1.9.4
Wrote PEAR system config file at: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/pear.conf
You may want to add: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php to your php.ini include_path
```

okay, so it thinks Pear is already installed, but I can't seem to reference it to do anything without the command not found error. I'm thinking that there's some sort of conflict as it's already installed as part of MAMP, but that the MAMP version isn't being referenced through the command line?

I know very little about terminal commands. Is my thinking even on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the error message:

> You may want to add: **/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php**
>   to your php.ini include_path

There is the MAMP install of PHP & the systemwide PHP. You need to use the MAMP specific install of PHP. Try this command.

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php install-pear-nozlib.phar
```

Also, here are my notes on installing `phpunit` under Mac OS X 10.6.8. Should work for Mac OS X 10.9. Mind you this is for a system install of `phpunit` and not MAMP specific.

First get curl to get the `go-pear.phar`:

```
http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar > go-pear.phar
```

At this point you might need to edit your `.bash_profile` and add `/usr/local/pear/bin` to `$PATH`.

Now run `go-pear.phar`:

```
sudo php -q go-pear.phar
```

Set the `pear` channels:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
```

Might need to explicitly indicate with `pear` you need when running the commands so this can work as well:

```
sudo /usr/local/pear/bin/pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo /usr/local/pear/bin/pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo /usr/local/pear/bin/pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo /usr/local/pear/bin/pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
```

Now install `phpunit`:

```
sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Now edit `php.ini`:

```
sudo nano /etc/php.ini
```

Find the `includes` path entry:

```
;include_path = ".:/php/includes/"
```

Uncomment—if it is commented—and change it to include the `pear` path:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/pear/share/pear:/php/includes/"
```